# Suggested Edits feature belongs in tools

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, suggested-edits

I like the 'suggested edits' feature but I don't like how it appears on SO.  If there is a suggested edit the content of the toolbar gets shifted left to make room for the number.  I find this distracting; I prefer the toolbar to never shift around (unless I'm getting rep/badges, of course).

I say remove the notification from the toolbar and move it to the tools screen, in a new tab called 'edits.'  Obviously the tools page would have to be made available to users who wouldn't normally have access to it, but the tabs that support features they don't have access to can be hidden.

If the notification must be in the toolbar, create a fixed width space for it and for god's sake don't give it that reddish orange background.  I think this number (with its red-orange background color) stands out too much for what I think feature that belongs in tools.

Comment: I hear you - my related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77635/suggested-edits-toolbar-widget

Comment: I changed it so notification is suppressed until the queue reaches 5 on stack overflow, I agree that constantly distracting you with notifications is a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I think it should be the other way around.  Put flags up there as well in a similar manner so those who have the power to moderate such things are strongly encouraged to do so.  The edits feature is currently experiencing a delay of only about 20-30 seconds from suggestion to approval/rejection, and that's fantastic.  Think of all the work that could be accomplished if flagged posts received that quick attention.

Comment: And if you don't like how obvious it is, the answer is simple - post a lot of bounties until you no longer have the power to perform those actions.  ;-D

Answer (score 1):

I am declining this for now, the recent change I made ensures people are only distracted if the queue grows beyond 5. This number is adjustable.

I do not want our 1000 10k users constantly interrupted and think this is a reasonable balance.

It is critical we deal with suggested edits early, dealing with a big fat queue is daunting and due to the blocking nature of edits, we need to unblock them as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine that it's there, but from a UX point-of-view having elements appearing and disappearing is unexpected and irritating. I have proposed that the icon be a "gray zero" when there are no edits. This will at least stop the toolbar from boinging around:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77635/suggested-edits-toolbar-widget

However, I do think that there is some mileage in actually removing it from the home page - **if** - that is what the user wants. I am finding it distracting at the moment, and often when I click it the edit is approved anyway. I think I contribute substantially via answers, edits, and new user liaison without being annoyed with blinking widgets.